# How to remove '.' from column names in a dataframe?

Tags: r

My dataframe which I read from a csv file has column names like this

`abc.def, ewf.asd.fkl, qqit.vsf.addw.coil`

I want to remove the '.' from all the names and convert them to

`abcdef, eqfasdfkl, qqitvsfaddwcoil.`

I tried using the sub command  `sub(".","",colnames(dataframe))` but this command took out the first letter of each column name and the column names changed to

`bc.def, wf.asd.fkl, qit.vsf.addw.coil`

Anyone know another command to do this. I can change the column name one by one, but I have a lot of files with 30 or more columns in each file.

Again, I want to remove the "." from all the colnames. I am trying to do this so I can use "sqldf" commands, which don't deal well with "."

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**1)** sqldf can deal with names having dots in them if you quote the names:

```
library(sqldf)
d0 <- read.csv(text = "A.B,C.D\n1,2")
sqldf('select "A.B", "C.D" from d0')
```

giving:

```
  A.B C.D
1   1   2
```

**2)** When reading the data using `read.table` or `read.csv` use the `check.names=FALSE` argument.

Compare:

```
Lines <- "A B,C D
1,2
3,4"
read.csv(text = Lines)
##   A.B C.D
## 1   1   2
## 2   3   4
read.csv(text = Lines, check.names = FALSE)
##   A B C D
## 1   1   2
## 2   3   4
```

however, in this example it still leaves a name that would have to be quoted in sqldf since the names have embedded spaces.

**3)** To simply remove the periods, if `DF` is a data frame:

```
names(DF) <- gsub(".", "", names(DF), fixed = TRUE)
```

or it might be nicer to convert the periods to underscores so that it is reversible:

```
names(DF) <- gsub(".", "_", names(DF), fixed = TRUE)
```

This last line could be alternatively done like this:

```
names(DF) <- chartr(".", "_", names(DF))
```

Answer (score 7):

To replace all the dots in the names you'll need to use gsub, rather than sub, which will only replace the first occurrence.

This should work.

```
test <- data.frame(abc.def = NA, ewf.asd.fkl = NA, qqit.vsf.addw.coil = NA)
names(test) <- gsub( ".",  "", names(test), fixed = TRUE)
test
  abcdef ewfasdfkl qqitvsfaddwcoil
1     NA        NA              NA
```

Comment: `sub` vs `gsub` is a good point, but it since OP also needs `fixed = TRUE` it would be good to explain that.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE dplyr 0.8.0**

As of dplyr 0.8 `funs()` is soft deprecated, use formula notation.

a `dplyr` way to do this using `stringr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(abc.def = 1, ewf.asd.fkl = 2, qqit.vsf.addw.coil = 3)
renamed_data <- data %>%
  rename_all(~str_replace_all(.,"\\.","_")) # note we have to escape the '.' character with \\
```

Make sure you install the packages with `install.packages()`.

Remember you have to escape the `.` character with `\\.` in regex, which functions like `str_replace_all` use,  `.` is a wildcard.

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if included the current version at the top, rather than in an *edit* at the bottom. (If you want to keep the old version, sticking that at the bottom would be more appropriate.) Also, it's incorrect to say that in R `.` is a wildcard - `.`  is a wildcard in regex. Another good option would be to use `fixed(".")` instead of `"\\."`. This data is far too small to matter, but `fixed()` will be quite a lot faster on large data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
names(df) = gsub(pattern = ".", replacement = "", x = names(df))
```